# Script para buscar y extraer lineas de un archivo txt

Tags: script, batch

Tengo un archivo de log de una aplicación y necesito extraer de este registro algunas líneas para enviarlo por correo electrónico.
Me gustaría hacerlo desde `.cmd` `.bat` . He hecho algunos scritps **(BATs)** para enviar correos electrónicos con BLAT, y recientemente con PowerShell, para estos comandos puedo especificar un archivo, ***por ejemplo*** `emailbody.txt` como el cuerpo del correo electrónico.

Entonces, tengo un ApplicationLog.txt, con aproximadamente 2000 líneas.
Lo que quiero hacer es buscar una cadena única en ApplicationLog.txt y extraer las 6 líneas siguientes a un nuevo archivo emailbody.txt

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Con el comando `findstr error ApplicationLog.txt` encontrarás las líneas con el texto "error". No sé cómo hacer para que te dé las líneas con el texto + las 6 siguientes.

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre que podria quedar como sigue:
al ejectuarlo le pasas el pattern a buscar algo como `sh file_name.sh "^pattern$"`
para usar awk debes instalarlo primero

```
#!bin/sh
pattern=$1
# obtienes el numero de linea donde se encuentra el pattern
line_number=$(grep -nE $pattern ApplicationLog.txt | grep -oE "^[0-9]+")
# un ciclo for para leer las 6 lineas
for i in `seq 0 6`;
        do
            line=$(($i + $line_number))
            #con awk obienes la linea n de un archivo y lo escribes en el archivo de salida
        awk "NR==$line" ApplicationLog.txt >> emailbody.txt
        done
```

espero ayudar, saludos...

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero estoy en ambiente Windows...

Comment: puedes usar como base este ejemplo, y usar findstr como lo dice @jotaelesalinas y la awk esta disponible para windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Comment: Buenisimo, lo voy a intentar, gracias